# Files defined in conffiles not installed on first install

Tags: debian

Short: Files defined in conffiles, do not install in first installation.

I am using CMake to create a debian package. This package works as I expect.
Within the package I have a configuration file that I would like to keep unmodified when I upgrade the package.
I defined the file in the `conffiles` control file in the debian package.
This also works as expected when I upgrade the file:

1. If unchanged, it retains the original file. When I update the contents of the config file, I get prompted if I want to keep the original file/update/etc.

However when I install the package for the first time on a new system, the files that are defined in the conffiles control file are not installed in the package.
According to the documentation: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html
When you install the package for the first time, they should install with all the other files, however the files are missing.

1. I know the file is present in my debian package, as I verified this and without the conffiles control file it is added.
2. I suppose the entry in conffiles is correct because on updating the behaviour is as expected.

Question: What is preventing the files in the conffiles control to be installed on the first installation?

Comment: The CMake toolchain does not produce fully compliant packages, just something that usually works. If these packages go to actual users, it makes sense to treat packaging as a separate action, and use the normal Debian packaging toolchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Deleted" is also a valid state for a configuration file that is kept across upgrades, as long as the package is in a state where conffiles remain, such as when the package is removed without purging configuration files.

If the conffile is installed when you install with either `--force-confnew` or `--force-confmiss`, that is an indication that the conffile was previously registered with dpkg, and is known to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was testing this and it did not occur to me, that if you uninstall a package, it does not necessarily uninstall the (modified) configuration files too. This clears it up.

Comment: @JanJaap in your question, you said “when I install the package for the first time on a new system”; does the above mean that that’s not accurate? If so, please edit your question accordingly. If you want to test package installations, you need to purge existing packages, not remove them (removing leaves configuration in place, including remembering deleted files; purging deletes everything).